# Quick way to see variables that apply in current scope and which object self refers to, RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a quick way to find out which variables apply with the current scope, and which object 'self' refers to in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: you can use a debugger and place it where you want to examine things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like using the Better Errors gem, then I just "raise @somevar" where I need, that way I can use the in browser console and poke it with a stick. :) god I love that thing.

Comment: I posted this before I learned about pry debugger . I would deferrer you to try pry.

Answer (score 36):

I think [`pry`](http://pryrepl.org/) is a great solution, although `debugger`, as @jvnill suggested, also works.

```
gem install pry # or add to bundler
```

In your code you need to add the following wherever you are interested in inspecting the scope:

```
require 'pry'
binding.pry # this will open a console view with the binding as the current scope
```

In `pry` there is something built in for what you're asking:

```
pry> ls
```

`ls` will show variables and methods that can be called and from which objects/classes they originate.

```
pry> self # will return self in the current context
pry> pry-backtrace # shows the current stack
pry> help # will show the list of commands
pry> cd <some obj> # will change the scope to the target object
pry> exit # move back out to previous console scope
```

Clarify if you are looking for something entirely different.

Comment: And if your rails app is being served by apache for development, try remote-pry.

Answer (score 7):

Using the gem "pry", issue the command "ls -l" in the context of pry for a list of local variables (together with values in the variables).

Comment: And `ls -i` for instance variables.